# finding line in very big file end with loop(probably)

Tags: python, database, loops, file, while-loop

I have two big files(644g and 23 gb) with milions of lines. In my calculations, before creating these files, it was because the smaller one my computer checks in 11 seconds and the larger one in 5 minutes. Each of these lines has a sequence of characters and each subsequent one is like it. When I search for a given line in this file, the search time is much longer than I assumed and it is endless. I have an impression that my "for" function is looping. I wonder whether not to add a line to the end of the file, e.g. "it's over" and add to the code that if it finds "it's over" it should do something else.
Part of my code:

```
    if licznik > 2:
        for line in b:
            if not line.startswith(number): continue 
            play_max()
    elif licznik = 0:
        for line in a:
            if not line.startswith(number): continue 
            play_max()
```

Also i want add thing that if cannot find the line in file it gonna do "play_one()"

IDK maybe this can be asnwear?:

```
elif licznik == 0:
    for line in a:
        if not line.startswith(hasz):
            play_one()
        play_max()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the while-loop never stops, because it is always True. You need something to stop it once the file is finished. For the adition of `play_one()`, I assume that `play_max()` also contains something that will break this while-loop or stop the script.

```
end_of_file = False
while not end_of_file:
    if licznik > 2:
        for line in b:
            if not line.startswith(number): continue 
            play_max()
        end_of_file = True
        play_one()
    elif licznik == 0:
        for line in a:
            if not line.startswith(number): continue 
            play_max()
        end_of_file = True
        play_one()
```

Also `elif licznik = 0` should be `elif licznik == 0`

Comment: i think i need something instead of continue. I just need to check file for "number" and when it found do: play_max() and when not found do: play_one() That while loop can delete

Comment: Then your question and your example are not clear. Why not just do something like `if number in b: play_max(); else: play_one()`?